# Best solution for clickable search list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm developing an app in Rails with a nutrient database. Now I'm looking for an easy solution for users to search the database through a search field, which as they type will present a list of records from the database, which at the same time are clickable and once clicked will direct them directly to the show path of that nutrient.

I'm thinking of something like [this](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/list). If you enter e. g. "burger" it does exactly what I need.

I've been researching now for some days and found solutions from jQuery autocomplete to Elasticsearch to typeahead.js but now I'm totally lost, which solution would be the right one for my usecase (I tried jQuery autocomplete but at the end it turned out that this is not exactly what I need).

Anybody some ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Algolia](https://www.algolia.com) is a well known solution for instant search, but not the easiest one to implement (though their support team is incredible).

You should look into [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) which is based on elasticsearch, and has an instant search feature. 
It is relatively easy to implement, and pretty well documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Searchkick sounds like a solid solution. Will check this out.